# Parse HTML table after clicking a button to make it visible

Tags: java, web-scraping, html-table, jsoup, html-parsing

I am working on a Java program that needs to read data from a website when it launches.

The website in question is this: http://bitcoincharts.com/charts/btceUSD#rg10zigHourlyztgSzm1g10zm2g25zv

To access the table that is needed, there is a button near the bottom of the page titled "Load raw data." When clicked, the table with the information that I need appears.

While I've never done it before, I believe that I can easily learn how to parse the table and get it into some arrays. What I haven't been able to figure out, though, is how to have my program "click" that button to make the table appear. How can I go about doing this?

Edit: here is what I am working with right now. Currently this prints absolutely nothing, and I suspect that it's because jsoup is not seeing the table because the "Load raw data" button has not been "clicked."

```
for (Element table : doc.select("table[id=chart_table]")) {
    for (Element row : table.select("tr:gt(2)")) {
        Elements tds = row.select("td:not([rowspan])");
        for (Element element : tds) {
            System.out.println(element);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: please post some of your codes,that you have tried till now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To click links and get other interactive client scripts executed, you might want to drop `Jsoup` for it and use [`HtmlUnit`](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/) instead. You would get the functionality you need to click links and scrape the HTML page too.

For your purpose, you are accessing a link with the dynamic data population through `ajax`. To replicate this scenario you would have to capture the `HtmlElement` and render the page again by clicking it.

Something like this:

```
final WebClient webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.FIREFOX_17,
                YOUR_PROXY_HOST, YOUR_PROXY_PORT);

        WebRequest request = new WebRequest(
                new URL(
                        "http://bitcoincharts.com/charts/btceUSD#rg60ztgSzm1g10zm2g25zv"));

        webClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false);
        webClient.setJavaScriptTimeout(10000);
        webClient.getOptions().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webClient.setAjaxController(new NicelyResynchronizingAjaxController());
        webClient.getOptions().setTimeout(10000);

        HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage(request);
        webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScript(30000);

        List<HtmlAnchor> anchors1 = page.getAnchors();
        HtmlAnchor link2 = null;
        for (HtmlAnchor anchor : anchors1) {
            //System.out.println(anchor.asText());
            if (anchor.asText().indexOf("Load raw data") > -1) {
                link2 = anchor;
                break;
            }
        }
        page = link2.click();
```

Now you handle the rendered data. Probably like:

```
HtmlTable table = (HtmlTable) page.getElementById("chart_table");
System.out.println("Here : - > " + table.asText());
```

The only complication I can see is as it is an ajax call, it might be a little tricky to render the page after a few seconds. The FAQ page on HtmlUnit provides for a few options to overcome it:

http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/faq.html#AJAXDoesNotWork

**EDIT:**
Well I just tried my code above (out of curiosity, of course) and it scrapes out the entire data you are looking for, screenshot below:

[image]

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your link, it looks as though all the link does is execute the javascript code "load_table();return false;". This means that instead of clicking the link, you can send the page these commands and access the table that way instead.

Answer (score 0):

The data of the table are dynamic and generated via javascript. When you press the link an ajax request is sent and the data are received. A parser like Jsoup can't handle dynamic elements because it can't render javascript. Check selenium for that. It includes a js engine, so you can execute js and then parse the data.

**EDIT**

After some digging I found this http://bitcoincharts.com/about/markets-api/. It seems that the page includes a REST service that you can hit and get the data you want. Maybe this is a better way to get the data you want, although it may have some usage limit.