# Parsing error jsoup Android

Tags: java, android, html-parsing, getelementbyid

This is the code i tried but always get error during parsing

```
Elements sezioni = tabella.getElementsByClass("grid grid-pad");
                                for(Element sezione : sezioni)
                                {

                                        Elements righe_sezione = sezione.getElementsByClass("col-1-1");                                       
                                        for(Element riga : righe_sezione)
                                        {

                                                Element info = riga.getElementsByClass("text").first();


                                                String titolo = riga.getElementsByTag("h2").first().text();


                                                String date= info.getElementsByClass("date").first().text();


                                                titoli.add(titolo);
                                                data.add(date);
                                        }
                                }
```

And i can't parsing the title and the date of articles..what's wrong? the page to parse is http://multiplayer.it/articoli/

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`jsoup` uses css based selectors, hence your `grid grid-pad` would translate to `grid-pad` itself.

Now there seems to be a flaw in the code where `grid-pad` and `col-1-1` do not cover the repetitive `divs` for the textual content you are looking for.

However, changing your selector to `text` and `archive_box` seem to do the trick as all of the content is within this div with css selector `archive_box`.

Hence your code skips 1 loop and just loops over `text`, like this:

```
try {
            Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://multiplayer.it/articoli/")
                    .get();
            Elements sezioni = doc.getElementsByClass("archive_box");
            for (Element riga : sezioni) {

                Element info = riga.getElementsByClass("text").first();

                String titolo = riga.getElementsByTag("h2").first().text();
                System.out.println(titolo);

                String date = info.getElementsByClass("date").first().text();
                System.out.println(date);

            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

**The output would be:**

```
Carmageddon è gratuito per un giorno su App Store e Google Play
circa un'ora fa
Paradox Interactive annuncia Runemaster
circa un'ora fa
Annunciato Hearts of Iron IV
circa un'ora fa
...
```

Comment: It works but only in the console.. Why i can't add the data and title in the ArrayList?

Comment: @End.Game I am printing it to console, you can easily place these 2 in your desired collection instances, after all these are normal String values which are getting printed with each iteration.

Comment: Ok ok, sorry now it works.my fault I forgot to initialize the array list :-) anyway, do you think it's possible crate a pagination with jsoup?I mean, as you can see in that page there is a pagination..do you think is possible do it with jsoup to see the articles in the next pages?

Comment: jsoup doesn't handle dynamic pages/content but only static html elements. You can use [HtmlUnit](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/) for dynamic behavior. Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21106431/parse-html-table-after-clicking-a-button-to-make-it-visible/21113377#21113377) answer out which was an attempt to handle an ajax based page. All the best!

Comment: Thank you @PopoFibo. I see you are good with jsoup so can you help me with this problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21330020/jsoup-parsing-page-knowing-url? I need navigate through the articles i parsed. I can parse each url but i really don't know how could parse each content page. If you could help me i'll be very glad.