# Jsoup parsing page knowing Url

Tags: java, android, parsing, href

I'm in front of a very big problem to me.. I'm parsing this page http://multiplayer.it/articoli/ with inside some articles.. As you can see, there are some informations i can parse: Tile, date of the article, comments and little preview of the article.

**THE GOAL** :
My goal is click on the article i parse(this operation it's already ok, i have the list with the informations i wrote below) and `onClick` i want enter in the article itself to see the content. Example: if i click in the first article right now, it brings me at this URL: http://multiplayer.it/notizie/127771-peter-moore-getta-acqua-sul-fuoco-e-descrive-nintendo-come-un-grande-partner-per-ea.html with all content i need view. The appplication has to do the same.

**THE PROBLEM**
I don't know how can do it. But parsing the url of each post i can know the absolute path of post. I can parse it in this way:

```
try {

                        Document doc = Jsoup.connect(BLOG_URL).get();
                        Elements links = doc.select("div.col-1-1 h2 a[href]"); 

                        for(Element sezione : links)
                        {

                            Log.d("Links",  sezione.attr("abs:href"));
                        }
                    } catch (Exception e) {

                        Log.e("ERROR", "Parsing Error");
                    }
```

And it returns each href.

**QUESTION**

Is it possible knwoing the href parse each page content? (the `'p'` tag) Thanks

OnClick method

```
lista.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                        int position, long id) {
                    //What here?
                }
            });
```

Comment: So you want to click the url and scrape the elements off of the 'resulting' page?

Comment: Yes! This is exactly what i want. tapping over an article in my list i want "enter" in it's url. I don't know if you understand :) i need fetch each child.

Comment: @PopoFibo are you still here?

Comment: yes very much, drafting a response :)

Comment: ups sorry :) i'm waiting for the answere :) Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`jsoup` wouldn't handle your dynamic actions on a web page. You would need to use an API which can handle these dynamic executions - an example being [`HtmlUnit`](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/).

Let's say you have a possibility all the links stored as part of a Java Collection instance like an `ArrayList`. If I try to parse the first url in the form of a specific method (which can be looped over to get the contents at runtime for all the url on your page dynamically):

**Using HtmlUnit**

```
public static void main(String... args)
            throws FailingHttpStatusCodeException, IOException {
        final WebClient webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.FIREFOX_17);

        WebRequest request = new WebRequest(
                new URL(
                        "http://multiplayer.it/articoli/"));

        webClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false);
        webClient.setJavaScriptTimeout(10000);
        webClient.getOptions().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webClient.setAjaxController(new NicelyResynchronizingAjaxController());
        webClient.getOptions().setTimeout(10000);

        HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage(request);
        webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScript(10000);

        System.out.println("Current page: Articoli videogiochi - Multiplayer.it");

        // Current page:
        // Title=Articoli videogiochi - Multiplayer.it
        // URL=http://multiplayer.it/articoli/

        List<HtmlAnchor> anchors1 =  page.getAnchors();
        HtmlAnchor link2 = null;
        for(HtmlAnchor anchor: anchors1)
        {
             if(anchor.asText().indexOf("Dead Rising 3: Operation Broken Eagle") > -1 )
             {
                  link2 = anchor;
                  break;
             }
        }
        page = link2.click();

        System.out.println("Current page: Dead Rising 3: Operation Broken Eagle - Recensione - Xbox On...");

        // Current page:
        // Title=Dead Rising 3: Operation Broken Eagle - Recensione - Xbox On...
        // URL=http://multiplayer.it/recensioni/127745-dead-rising-3-operation-broken-eagle-una-delle-storie-di-los-perdidos.html


        webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScript(10000);

        DomNodeList<DomElement> paras = page.getElementsByTagName("p");
        for (DomElement el : paras.toArray(new DomElement[paras.size()])) {
            System.out.println(el.asText());
        }
    }
```

In the above code, it displays all the `<p>` available on the landing page. Below is the screenshot of the output:

[image]

In the above code block, you have the ability to loop over all the anchor tags on the web page, and I choose a specific anchor link to get the resulting content:

```
List<HtmlAnchor> anchors1 =  page.getAnchors();
            HtmlAnchor link2 = null;
            for(HtmlAnchor anchor: anchors1)
            {
                 if(anchor.asText().indexOf("Dead Rising 3: Operation Broken Eagle") > -1 )
                 {
                      link2 = anchor;
                      break;
                 }
            }
```

You might want to right an appropriate logic to parse all the dynamic links on your page and display their contents.

**EDIT:**

You can try generating these dynamic scripts through [htmlunitscripter](https://code.google.com/p/htmlunitscripter/) Firefox plugin and customize it later to your needs too.

Comment: Wow amazing answere!! Thanks! So, how it works with method onClick? Take a look at my edit with onClick method

Comment: and, have i to open a new activity to display the new content?

Comment: Well the above is a standalone example which takes care of clicking the url and getting the contents. I guess for you needs you might want to try from `page = link2.click();` onwards (this is where the page gets automatically clicked).

Comment: I have to study this method because seems complicated :(. For example.. I already can't understand if i have to create another activity in wich display the content of every page and how pass the data onClick.

Comment: I'm trying launching the application but seems wont starts. mmh... is the library for android too right?

Comment: do you think is the only way?

Comment: It should work if you have correct lib references. I think this is the only way unless you have the ability to manually traverse to the links and then scrape the data.

Comment: i was thinking, i have the array of each link.. if onClick on item list i make a intent that goes at the arrayLink position? Is it possible? And it open a new activity in which i parse the content of that link. I don't know if i'm clear

Comment: @End.Game I'm lost on the parts which are specific to your design. maybe post your attempt with the code and we can take it further, I guess!