# Jsoup href with function jscript

Tags: java, jsoup, jscript

Guys I'm using the JSoup library to extract some data from a html page, but now I'm needing to jump to the next page, and this link on the next line.

```
<a class="jsEnabled nextBtn cursorPointer" href="javascript:setSelectedLink('NextPageButton');" title="Next page" alt="Next page"></a>
```

Ie, he is in a jscript function, how do I do to get the link dynamically?

Comment: Take a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21106431/parse-html-table-after-clicking-a-button-to-make-it-visible/21113377#21113377) to get an idea.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately jsoup ***can't execute javascripts***. But you can use other libraries, eg. [HtmlUnit](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/) do do so.

Did you check if the website has some plain html alternatives in, which allow you to get to the next page?

Comment: I found no alternative link

Comment: Then you have to use a additional library for javascript execution. I'll insert a link to htmlunit into my answer.

Comment: Pleas see the [Getting Started](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/gettingStarted.html) Page.